How to add an apt trusted key to an offline server?
I have an online server and an offline server, both running Ubuntu 20.04.
To install php8.2 on the online server, all I need to do is run sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php which will add a trusted gpg key to the server along with the repository.
My question is, how do I do so on the offline server?
Things I have tried:

I copied the key directly from /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ from the online server to the offline server, along with the sources.list addition. However when I run sudo apt-offline install MyFolder, I keep getting ERROR: MyFolder/ppa.launchpad.net_ondrej_php_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease bad signature.  Not syncing because in strict mode.. I could use sudo apt-offline install --allow-unauthenticated MyFolder but it's not recommended (it also yields ERROR: Disabling apt gpg check can risk your machine to compromise.).

I used apt download $(apt-rdepends XYZ | grep -v "^ " | sed 's/debconf-2.0/debconf/g') on the online server where XYZ represents each package/dependency and installed everything on the offline server using dpkg -i *.deb. But now I'm wondering how to update/upgrade or install a new module, since the sub-versions are not available (e.g. offline server requires php8.2-common_8.2.19, but repo only has php8.2-common_8.2.22 available).



php8.2-common is not in any Ubuntu repository. You got it from somewhere else. You could ask that repo maintainer.

The older deb package might still be in your  /var/cache/apt/archives...unless you have run apt clean or apt autoclean, which would delete it.

@user535733, I started my question with add-apt-repository which adds a repository outside of Ubuntu, thanks. My question was how to do the same on an offline server, especially because I can update with apt-offline.
Anyway, I downloaded the latest php8.2-common and manually installed using dpkg -i *.deb. I am hoping to find a way to include external repos into apt-offline updates.
